# How to make a SVG map in android? (and place markers on the map)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, svg

I'm making an app for a real life game. The app needs to use a custom map that uses scalar vector graphics (SVG). The map I'm using provides very accurate detail, such as door locations inside a building; This is why i'm using SVG instead of the maps api.
Now I know there is an api for svg (http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/), so here is what I need help with:

1) The image must be zoomable. The only reason for using the SVG graphics is for clean zooming.

2) I need to place dynamic markers (images, or buttons w/ numbers) on the SVG image. An SQL table has an image, and a location. The table will be updated, added to, and removed from. I need to place said images on top of the SVG image, and possibly each other. Coordinates and math aside, how do I place the images on top of each other (can't use XML since they aren't static).

I need to use Android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

The default browser in 2.2 doesn't support SVG. You can target Opera Mobile, which supports SVG and other new technology much better, but it won't be a *native* app.

The first step I'd try would be designing the interface in Inkscape, then you can reference the .svg file from HTML and move elements with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

flying-pigs,

If i understand your question, you want to display a SVG like [that](http://bienvenue.chateauversailles.fr/fr/chateau/bienvenue#!panel-0-subpanel-15) on your phone ? So you can display user location on that map.

I describe a working solution here : [Add SVG Tile Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580235/googlemaps-tileprovider-using-a-single-svg-map#_=_)

Let me know if you have other questions about GG Map