# Googlemaps TileProvider using a single SVG Map

Tags: android, google-maps, svg

In my Android application, I want to display a simple Map with scrolling and zooming capabilities. I don't want to rely on network connection for the map, so everything has to be shipped with the application.

I have a single SVG file of the country I want to show (only land mass and/or water is important for me). I figured that the best way to display the map would be a Google Maps View with a custom `TileProvider`, that generates the tiles dynamically from the SVG file.

However, it seems as if I would need to do the math, that somehow maps real coordinates (the `x` and `y` I am getting in the `TileProvider`) onto  the SVG scale, myself, which sounds like a non-trivial thing to do.

Is there any other option I didn't think of that does not involve shipping megabytes of tiles with my app? Are there maybe existing libraries that do the stuff for me? Should I use a completely different approach?

Comment: `sounds like a non-trivial thing to do` is not a good starting point for getting your question answered. Show your effort in solving the problem. You cannot be a good programmer if math scares you.

Comment: Math doesn't scare me at all. Yet I don't want to reinvent the wheel and before I start tailoring my own solution I wanted to learn about possible alternatives. I realize that the question is not very specific, but at the current stage I am looking for the best (general) way to solve the problem rather than some specific implementation.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hope that it's not too late =)

Actually i found 2 solutions :

- You can use this library : [SVGMapView](https://github.com/jiahuanyu/SVGMapView)
- The 2nd solution was developed by Google in the Application :

[Google IO 2015](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/map/util/SVGTileProvider.java)

Comment: please summarize the links in your answer

Comment: Hi Noam, actually i prefer the solution provided by Google I/O app. Globally, you can include [SVG jars](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/third_party/svg-android/libs/svg-android-2.0.7-20150515.214425-1.jar) in your project. This library comes form [Android-SVG](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android) but it was modified by Google to fix a crash on Android M. You can then create your own  SVGTileProvider. Note that you have to provide your Cartisian Coordinates of your SVG on the Map for the function setPolyToPoly. Hope that will answer to your question.